# Junit using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 - Exception in constructor: Stub

Tags: android, intellij-idea, junit4

I'm just starting to use JUNIT with Android testing. I'm currently attempting to use it to test a DAO object. I'm using intellij as the IDE.

I've gathered that I shoudl use a test class extending ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2, and use the instrumentation facilities there to get the context needed to initiate the DAO object.

**This is my test class:**

```
package br.com.pcontop.vigilantes.model;

import android.content.*;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import br.com.pcontop.vigilantes.view.PaginaDia;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

import java.io.*;

public class EntradaPontosDAOTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<PaginaDia> {
    Context context;

    public EntradaPontosDAOTest() {
        super("br.com.pcontop.vigilantes.view", PaginaDia.class);

    }

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        context = getInstrumentation().getContext();
    }
    public void testBusqueEntradasComecandoCom() throws Exception {
        //assertNotNull(context);
        EntradaPontosDAO entradaPontosDAO = new EntradaPontosDAO(context);
        //assertNotNull(entradaPontosDAO);

    }
}
```

**As I run the test, the following exception is thrown:**

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Exception in constructor: testBusqueEntradasComecandoCom (java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.<init>(InstrumentationTestCase.java:5)
    at android.test.ActivityTestCase.<init>(ActivityTestCase.java:5)
    at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.<init>(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:5)
    at br.com.pcontop.vigilantes.model.EntradaPontosDAOTest.<init>(EntradaPontosDAOTest.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.createTest(TestSuite.java:61)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.addTestMethod(TestSuite.java:294)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.addTestsFromTestCase(TestSuite.java:150)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.<init>(TestSuite.java:129)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.<init>(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit3Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit3Builder.java:14)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:98)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:84)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit46ClassesRequestBuilder.collectWrappedRunners(JUnit46ClassesRequestBuilder.java:69)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit46ClassesRequestBuilder.getClassesRequest(JUnit46ClassesRequestBuilder.java:40)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4TestRunnerUtil.buildRequest(JUnit4TestRunnerUtil.java:81)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
)
```

**The line in question is this, in the contructor:**

```
    super("br.com.pcontop.vigilantes.view", PaginaDia.class);
```

I've tried alredy placing the junit jar over the others in the project's classpath. It now works well in tests extending TestCase. This still don't do the trick for the test above.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try removing the first parameter and see if it works?

Comment: Actually, it was a question of putting junit up on the dependency chain. As Siddharth answered below.

Answer (score 1):

I fell upon this [link](http://mcondev.wordpress.com/2010/06/09/java-lang-runtimeexception-stub-at-junit-framework-testsuite-testsuite-java7-at-org-junit-internal-runners-junit38classrunner-junit38classrunner-java67-at-org-junit-internal-builders-junit3/#comment-201), hopefully it will be helpful. You need to move junit up the dependency chain in your build path settings.

Answer (score 0):

You should run your Android test cases in an Android device or emulator not on your development computer. The `android.jar` found on your SDK provides only stubs.

Comment: How do you tell maven to use your device or emulator?